# Not receiving IPNs in paypal sandbox

Tags: django, paypal, paypal-sandbox, django-paypal

"Instant Payment Notification (IPN) history" in sandbox paypal is empty although the following values are sent with [django-paypal](https://django-paypal.readthedocs.io/en/stable/standard/ipn.html):

```
    # Paypal initial values
    paypal_dict = {
        "business": settings.SANDBOX_PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL,
        "amount": "2.5",
        "currency_code": "GBP",
        "item_name": "item",
        "notify_url": request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('paypal-ipn')),
        "return": request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('blog:article', args=(ar_id, "payment_successful"))),
        "cancel_return": request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('blog:article', args=(ar_id, "payment_cancelled"))),
        "custom": "plan",
    }
```

[Paypal listener configuration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSetup/):

```
Notification URL    https://www.<mysite.com>/paypal/
Message delivery    Enabled
```

All payments succeed but I don't receive any IPNs in the paypal sandbox account.

The [IPN simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/ipnSimulator/) works correctly and i receive IPNs in my website listener.

I am using django 3.0.2, django-paypal 1.0 and my website is online with https.

Comment: PayPal's support will be better equipped to tell you why a particular sandbox transaction did not trigger IPNs. They can see what's missing.  Make sure you're logging into an actual *sandbox* account ... https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_display-ipns-history

Comment: This is a customer-service question and cannot be solved by the public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah PayPal IPN Sandbox service is down.

> AFFECTED PRODUCTS: Notifications
>
> Initial Notification: Affected Regions: Global
>
> We're aware of an issue impacting instant payment notifications (IPN)
>   in the Sandbox environment. IPNs have not been generated since January
>   31, 2020. Teams are working to resolve this issue.

Link: https://www.paypal-status.com/incident/sandbox

Next time, check this page to see if one of their products/services is down:
https://www.paypal-status.com/product/sandbox

Comment: Thank you, I finally I integrated the smart button, it seems more useful solution for me

Comment: Cool! Just took a look at smart buttons, looks promising...

Answer (score 0):

> We're aware of an issue impacting instant payment notifications (IPN) in the Sandbox environment. IPNs have not been generated since January 31, 2020. Teams are working to resolve this issue.

Source : https://www.paypal-status.com/incident/sandbox

You can still test your notifications with the simulator.

Comment: lol, it's enough to mention my answer instead of making the same ;)

Comment: @parse Hello, check the time i posted my answer, it's before yours, but for your defense idk why a moderator deleted my answer and undeleted it :/

Comment: When I came to the post, i saw 0 answers to this question! maybe it's been hidden or something for review! I don't know